# Accessing Asp.Net Session variables in JS

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm not able to access the variable in my .js file

the code i have at the top of the page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    privilage = '<%=Session["privilage"]%>';
</script>
```

then i want to access privilage in my .js file.

i just want to alert this at the moment. would i be able to do this?

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? If you put an alert(privilage) after privilage = '<%=Session["privilage"]%>'; will it display the correct value?

Comment: your code is correct, it works on my machine.  I only used var privilage though ....

Comment: i  tried alert after declaring privilage = '<%=Session["privilage"]%>';

Comment: Your problem is that you're not running the code through the ASP.NET application server. JavaScript can only access what is sent to the browser, which does *not* include server-side session state. However, if you let the server process the <%= %> in your script before it is sent to the browser, the end result will be what you want.

Comment: Rythmis..Your correct .but,in my application the value is nedded without sending to the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store session Value in HiddenField.
After that You can Access the HiddneFieldValue in your JS

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('hdnField').value = '<%=Session["privilage"]%>';
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
var privilage = '<%=Session["privilage"]%>';
```

or try:

```
alert(privilage);
```

It will display your Session value

Comment: i tried on my machine it's giving '<%=Session["privilage"]%>' not the value

Comment: Is it located on an aspx page served by IIS or the web server in Visual Studio?

Comment: My aspx page served by IIS   @Tobias Nilsson

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var privilage = '<%=Session["privilage"]%>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it this way.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" CssClass="txtValue" style="display: none;" />
```

Then I use jQuery to access the value.

```
<script>
var txtValue = $(".txtValue").val();
</script>
```

Or even on a control.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrint" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"
CommandName="Print" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("PrintData") %>'
Text="<img src='/images/print_on.png' onmouseover='cursor: pointer;'
class='PrintButton' />" ToolTip="Print" OnClientClick="if ($('.txtValue').val()
!= '1') { $('.txtValue').val('1'); alert('Warning: Please enable pop-ups for
this site!'); }" />
```

This method survives ajax and postbacks.

Cheers