# Trying to get Session value in JS I keep getting literal code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session

Upon each login in ASP.NET I place the users username in the session like this

```
//..... 
if (PasswordHash.PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(LoginForm.Password, password))
{
    e.Authenticated = true;
    Session["Username"] = LoginForm.UserName;
}
//.....
```

Now I need to access that through JS and I thought I could just do this:

```
    if (won) {
        var username = '<%= Session["Username"] %>'
        alert("Congrats " + username + ", you won!");
    }
```

But I'm getting `Congrats <%= Session["Username"] %>, you won!` instead. Why is that? Judging by answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519454/how-can-i-access-session-variables-and-set-them-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213809/accessing-asp-net-session-variables-in-js) question I should be able to access it like that.

Comment: Are you using `<%= Session["Username"] %>` in JS file? It won't work there

Comment: @Satpal yes I am. I see. Now that I think of it it makes sense that it wouldn't work in the .js file. I guess I have to use Ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode your username into a div or a javascript variable.

Add this to the page where you are calling your javascript from

```
<div id="userinfo" data-user-name="<%= Session["Username"] %>">
```

and then read the data by using jquery

```
$('#userinfo').data('user-name')
```

For javascript add the following to your page

```
<script>
 var username = "<%= Session["Username"] %>";
</script>
```

And then you can use your variable in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to use something like this:

```
        if (won) {  
         $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "SomePage.aspx/GetUserName",        
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "text",
                   success: function (name) {
                      alert("Congrats " + name+ ", you won!");        
                   }
               });
        }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetUserName()
    {
    ...
      if (PasswordHash.PasswordHash.ValidatePassword(LoginForm.Password, password))
      {  
         return LoginForm.UserName;
      }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: for doing ajax call to aspx web method should be static. And question is get UserName from Session object...